# How to remove quotation marks in string?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a Kotlin project. In my app I have an edittext and when I send my edittext value to server it sends with quotation marks - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XFPJ.jpg. I don't want to use regex because user might enter some text with quotation marks. How can I remove these quotation marks?

Comment: Actually you can't use `'` for string rather than char so you should filter the single quote .`str.filter { " ' "}` maybe this kind of approach?

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu, it is json. You can't remove it. I need to remove quotation marks.

Comment: @DaniilAndreev That's strange, that's not gonna happen naturally, please edit your question and provide your code for sending data to server so people can help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code

```
text.replace("\"", "");
```

Forward slash (/) is just a regular character with no special meaning in the string.

P.S.
If the answer seems correct, click on the flag on the left :-)